# How to set up a Drupal site to communicate with an external Landing Page

Tags: commerce, services, importing-exporting

I have a client who runs several landing pages (non-Drupal) on remote servers. I don't have access to them. These pages collect the usual data – email/address/name etc.

Now the Drupal 7 site I'm working on (with Commerce shop) shall

1. receive an email-address from a landing page to check whether
   someone is already known or not
2. in case of recognizing the email-address send name/address/etc-data
   back to the landing page for further processing over there
3. finally receive a new or an updated set of data to be processed (in
   the Commerce shop), resulting in an email with a link to a page
   where a file can be downloaded (plus an email with Account-data for
   new customers)

In the best case the customer never sees the Drupal site.

I have already set up the shop, everything is working as expected if a customer would buy directly on site.

Now since the files to be exclusively "sold" via landing pages are free testversions of the software sold in the shop I'm not sure whether I need the shop for this procedure at all. Here I need some input on how to set up the whole process.

A few ideas:

- set up a secret form to be filled in by a landing page script/bot:
  how could the landing page collect possible data?
- use the services.module for data exchange: will this work in both
  directions? What would be the best way to accomplish the task using
  Services, both on the Landing pages and the Drupal site?
- use customized Rules derived from the shop to accomplish sending the
  desired mails?
- redirect the customer to the shop, prefill the cart, skip payment in
  checkout: this would not be the preferred solution?

I thought this should be a task not too bizarre, unfortunately it obviously is (to me at least). Any qualified pointing in the right direction?

Comment: I like a web services approach. You probably want to use oauth, but will probably need a custom resource to handle custom access callback.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I guess I'll stick with services. What do you think, will it be more reasonable to take the route via shop or to skip it?
I suppose I'd have to make orders available in a custom resource if I took the shop route, but maybe this was not necessary at all.